# Input Number Type Dollar Sign

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with a line that asks for a dollar amount, however if the user puts a dollar sign in front of the number the form won't let it send because it is set to type="number".

Is there a way to let a user type in a dollar sign ($) in the type="number" and have the form send with no issue?

Code:

```
<label>Monthly Budget</label>
<input name="budget" type="number" placeholder="$400.00" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Uh oh, somethings wrong!" data-errormessage-type-mismatch="Uh oh, somethings wrong!">
```

Comment: Since the `$` is virtual, and not needed. Just add it on the fly when displaying content. Money is not handled with dollar signs. It's all base integers. The currency type is just a symbol added to tell you what the numbers value is, in what country. If you must, you'd have to use `type="input"` or `type="text"`

Comment: The issue is the form will not send if the user adds the dollar sign. It is not user friendly.

Comment: Which is why you place the `$` before the input field as plain text so they know it's already there and don't write it again. Like I said, it's a symbol displayed only on the users side. It's not handled in code in most every case.

Answer (score 1):

Just denote the symbol before the input field so they don't add it again. Currency symbols aren't handled in code, they're added to the viewport for the users display on-the-fly.

```
<label>Monthly Budget</label>
<span class="input">&#36;<input name="budget" type="number" placeholder="400.00" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Uh oh, somethings wrong!" data-errormessage-type-mismatch="Uh oh, somethings wrong!"></span>
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/365m8/)

**[input type=number - Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)**

Comment: This is a good conclusion from the correct answer, but not an answer.

Comment: It actually is an answer, using standard practice. Just not a breaking standards answer. `type="number"` specifies that its input element is a precise control for setting the element’s value to a string representing a number. Precise, for a reason. There's no way around that without using setting to `text` or `input` without jQuery or JavaScript taking that value, and then submitting, but then why set a type? Don't troll.

Comment: No, it is not an answer to the question “Is there a way to let a user type in a dollar sign ($) in the type="number" and have the form send with no issue?”

Comment: The answer is "No" and, the alternative method is shown. It's an answer. Lol Don't troll.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to let a user type in a dollar sign in a `type="number"` field and have the form send with no issue is to intercept (with JavaScript) user input with keyboard event handlers such as `onkeyup`, remove the dollar sign, and clear the status with `setCustomValidity('')`. This would require some care, since keyboard event handling (and recognizing which character was entered) varies across browsers. More importantly, it would result in poor usability: the user could type “$42” but would see the “$” vanish, and could get very confused.

Putting the dollar sign in front of the field is one way (not completely reliable) of *avoiding* the problem of a user-entered dollar sign (rather than solving it). Note that there are other issues with the code, too, such as the use of a specific amount of money as a placeholder (use `value` if you wish to set an initial value) and not allowing any cents, contrary to what `400.00` suggests. A better idea:

```
<label for="budget">Monthly Budget</label>
<input id="budget" name="budget" type="number" 
placeholder="xxx.xx" 
required
step="0.01"
title="Amount of money in numbers">
```

(If you wish to disallow cents, which would be sensible for a budget, omit the `step` attribute, defaulting it to 1, and omit the `placeholder` attribute, since there’s probably no suitable value for it.)

Alternatively, use `input type="text"` and a suitable `pattern` attribute, e.g.

```
<input id="budget" name="budget" type="text" 
placeholder="xxx.xx" 
required
title="Amount of money in numbers"
pattern="\$?(\d)+(\.\d\d)?">
```

(to allow cents but not require them). Note that this would make (on supporting browsers) input like 400.000 or 400.5 invalid, which is probably good. This approach would imply that in form data handling, you would need to deal with an optional leading “$”, which is normally simple of course.